# Play Framework 2.0 Access foreign key object from template

Tags: templates, foreign-keys, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have 2 Ebean models connected with ManyToOne connection.

```
@Entity
public class Interview extends Model {
   @Id
   Long id;
   @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
   public User user;
   ....
}
```

And

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {
   @Id
   public Long id;
   @Email
   @Required
   @Column(unique=true)
   public String email;
   @Required
   public String name;
   public String department;
   public String phone;
....
}
```

When trying to access the User class fields from Scala template through the Interview instance I only have access to the id field, but others return empty string.
Here is the template:

```
@(interviewsList[Interview])
....
<table>
.....
    @for(i <- interviewsList) {
     <tr>
            <td>@i.user.name</td> // EMPTY, while changing to @i.user.id returns an id
            <td>@i.date.format("dd MMM yyyy")</td>
         </tr>
     }
 </table>
```

Is there any way to access other fields without using Finder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011874/why-ebean-returns-null-for-no-reason

Comment: Using getters for fields worked. Thanks!