# Ebean ManyToMany query

Tags: java, many-to-many, playframework-2.1, ebean

I have two classes, user and car. Both have ManyToMany mapping to each other.

User:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {

    private int year;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Car> cars;
}
```

Car:

```
@Entity
public class Car extends Model {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "cars", cascade=CascadeType.ALL )
    private List<User> users;
}
```

Using ebean, I would like to query only those cars from year 1999 that have give user in their list. I do not want to iterate over the user's car list in Java code.

I didn't find any documentation how many-to-many queries should look like. So I would something like this:

```
public List<Car> findCars(int year, User user) {
    return Car.find.where().eq("year", int).eq("users", user).findList();
}
```

Is this possible with Ebean?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check similar [question (and answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11704403/1066240)

Most probably your finder should look like:

```
public List<Car> findCars(int year, User user) {
    return find.where().eq("year", year).eq("users.id", user.id).findList();
}
```

BTW I assume that you have some `id` field but just didn't show us. Also make your fields public, so you won't need to write getters/setters for each.

Comment: I was using private fields as I had issues getting tests working without getters/setters. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011874/why-ebean-returns-null-for-no-reason

Comment: Yes with private fields, you need to write public getters, that's normal

Comment: Obviously :-) But the link in my comment describes bug/feature in Ebean / Play 2 combo I was referring to.