# Searching Ebean @ManyToMany

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm working on a program that receives tweets from the twitterstream, and stores them in the DB.

There is a Keyword Model, and a Tweet Model

The keyword model has a manytomany of tweets, ex.

```
@ManyToMany
List<Tweets> tweets;
```

I want to search tweets, and return only the ones that are assigned to that keyword. In vanilla SQL similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM tweet t, keyword k, keyword_tweet kt where t.id=kt.tweet_id and k.id=kt.keyword_id
```

Any idea how to do this in Play! using ebean?

Each Tweet has an ID, each keyword has an ID, Play automatically created another table "keyword_tweet" for the @ManyToMany association.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public List<Tweets> findTweets(Tweet t) {
     return Tweets.find
            .where()
            .eq("tweets.id", t.id)
            .findList();
}
```

Same as mentioned in [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419624/ebean-manytomany-query)