# play framework scala get join table attribute

Tags: java, scala, playframework, ebean

I am using Play framework with Ebean. I have two models, below are the code:

```
public class User extends Model {
    @Id 
    public Long id;

    public String name;
   /* rest of attributes */

    public static Finder<Long,User> find = new Finder<Long,User>(
          Long.class, User.class
    );
}

public class Admin extends Model {
    @Id 
    public Long id;

    @OneToOne
    public User user;
    /* rest of attributes */

    public static Finder<Long,Admin> find = new Finder<Long,Admin>(
        Long.class, Admin.class
    );
}
```

When I do `Logger.info(admin.user.name)` in Java, I can see the name of the admin. But when I pass the Java object to Scala using view render, if I do `@admin.user.id`, I can still get the id, but if I do `@admin.user.name`, I get nothing (with no error). I'm just wonder how can I access the name attribute from a joined table?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Ebean returns null for no reason?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011874/why-ebean-returns-null-for-no-reason)

Comment: I tried the method, but it doesn't help. I have no problem getting the User instance, but it return nothing when I try to access the variables of User (other than id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.
Before when I do the fetching, I did

```
Admin.find.where()
    .ilike("user.name", "%" + filter + "%")        
    .orderBy("user."+sortBy + " " + order)
    .findPagingList(pageSize)
    .getPage(page);
```

After changing to

```
Admin.find.fetch("user", new FetchConfig().query())
    .where()
    .ilike("user.name", "%" + filter + "%")        
    .orderBy("user."+sortBy + " " + order)
    .findPagingList(pageSize)
    .getPage(page);
```

It successfully displayed instance variables on Scala.